# how to send querys to mysql from angular

Tags: mysql, angularjs

first of all this is not a specific question it is more how to question.

I am making a angujarjs app from 0. And I am looking for alter sql query from angular so far I only found examples of how to receive data of an static query but that it is not a option for app I have in mind.

I tried to use different contention for mysql but could find one that works so far. The problem is that I just don't know how to do it and cant find any example.

edit :I know I need server code to communicate whit db I just want to send variables to my query like "john" in "SELECT name, phone FROM users WHERE name = 'john'"

Comment: This sounds like a huge security hole. If a user can send queries from angular that user can also alter those queries. Do you really want that to be a possibility. I think you should leave mysql querying to server side code

Comment: are we talking about adding variables to a query or are we talking about creating the query in angular? if your doing the latter Erik is totally right but if your talking about just changing a parameter then you can use an instance of node to handle the change from JSON in your app to SQL in your database. I have a full project that makes loads of these calls, let me know what you would exactly like to do.

Comment: joe yes it is what I am trying to do. At this point I just what to change a parameter in a simple select but I dont know where to start whit server side code I know more or less how handle js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must to implement a rest api that will create the query and return the result to the client code. Or just append your variables on the query of your url access, retrieve them on the server and run your query.

Example with the query params:

```
$http.get('//' + $window.location.host + '/users?name=' + user.name)
.then(success, fail)
```

If you are using plain php on the server :

```
$name = filter_var($_GET['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

I recommend to use PDO for your sql queries.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, phone FROM users WHERE name = :userName");
$stmt->bindParam(':userName', $name);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```